# Why constant symbols in a language?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

What is the point of constant symbols in a language?

For example we take the language of rings $(0,1,+,-,\cdot)$.
What is so special about $0,1$ now? What is the difference between 0 and 1 besides some other element of the ring?

I am aware, that you want to have some elements, that you call 0 and 1 which have the desired properties, like $x+0=0+x=x$ or $1\cdot x = x\cdot 1=x$.

Is there something else, which makes constants 'special'?

Other example: Suppose we have the language $L=\{c\}$ where $c$ is a constant symbol.
Now we observe the L-structure $\mathfrak{S}_n$  over the set $\mathbb{Z}$, where $c$ gets interpreted by $n$.

Is there any difference, between $c$ and $n$?
Or are they just the same and you can view it as some sort of substitution?

For $\mathfrak{S}_0$ we would understand $c$ as $0$.
Since there are no relation- or functionsymbols, we just have the set $\mathbb{Z}$ and could note them as

$\{\dotso, -1, c, 1, \dotso\}$

If we take the usual function $+$ and add it $L=\{c,+\}$ now $\mathfrak{S}_0$ has the property, that $c+c=c$ for example.

I hope you understand what I am asking for.

I think it boils down to:

> Is there a difference between the structure $\mathfrak{S}_n$ as L-structure and $\mathfrak{S}_n$ as $L_\emptyset$-structure, where $L_\emptyset=\emptyset$ (so does not contain a constant symbol).

But I want to get as much insight here as possible. So if you do not understand what I am asking for, it might be best, if you just take a guess. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the empty language, given any structure with more than one element, then there are no definable members in your structure. But once you add a constant, you add a definable element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An $L$-structure is not just a set, it is a set *together with* interpretations of the constant symbols, function symbols and relation symbols in $L$. You need to keep track of the interpretations as additional data so that you can do things like define *homomorphisms* of $L$-structures: namely, they're those functions that respect the interpretations of the symbols.

For example, "$\mathbb{Z}$ as a group" and "$\mathbb{Z}$ as a set" have the same underlying set, but the former additionally has (at least) a binary operation $+ : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, which must be preserved by group homomorphisms.

In your example, a homomorphism of $L$-structures $f : \mathfrak{S}_n \to \mathfrak{S}_m$ would be required to satisfy $f(n) = m$, since $n$ and $m$ are the respective interpretations of the constant $c$, but a homomorphism of $L_{\varnothing}$-structures would not.

So while "$\mathfrak{S}_n$ as an $L$-structure" and "$\mathfrak{S}_n$ as an $L_{\varnothing}$-structure" have the same underlying set, they are not the same object.

Fun fact: the assignment from "$\mathfrak{S}_n$ as an $L$-structure" to "$\mathfrak{S}_n$ as an $L_{\varnothing}$-structure" is an example of a [forgetful functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor).

Comment: Now I wonder, if structures $\mathfrak{S}_n, \mathfrak{S}_m$ can be isomorphic (for $n\neq m$) when you take $L=\{c,<\}$. Then it has to be $n<m\Leftrightarrow f(n)<f(m)$. But such an isomorphism must preserve the constant symbols. So $f(n)=m$ and $f(m)=n$ and for every other $z\neq m,n$ it is $f(z)=z$. But then you get $n<m\Leftrightarrow f(n)<f(m)$ so $n<m\Leftrightarrow m<n$?

Comment: @Cornman: Right, so what that tells you is that if $m \ne n$ then there is no isomorphism of $\{ c, < \}$-structures between $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $\mathfrak{S}_m$ (assuming that $<$ is interpreted as the usual order relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ in both $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $\mathfrak{S}_m$).

Answer (score 6):

Clive's answer is already a good one, I just wanted to add another important point about constants. They give us the power to say infinitely many things about one element.

For example, if we consider [Peano Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) then obviously $\mathbb N$ is a model. Now, add a constant $c$ to our language and add sentences $c > \bar n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ (where $\bar n$ stands for 1 added $n$ times: $1 + 1 + \ldots + 1$). This new theory is consistent by compactness, so it has a model $M$. In $M$ we have an interpretation for $c$, which is bigger than all natural numbers. So we obtain a nonstandard model of arithmetic. Something similar can be done to create a model that looks like the reals, but has infinitesimals.

Comment: Thank you. That is insightful. I was wondering if you take $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual language of a field and add the constant symbols of $\pi$ and $e$, where $\pi=3,1415\dotso$ and $e=2.71828\dotso$ as usual. Then there would be no point in adding those constants? Because these 'symbols' already exist in the structure with the same behavior.

Comment: Actually, there would be a point. These are not algebraic numbers, so they cannot be defined in $\mathbb R$ in the language of a field. In the language of a field, there is a model of $Th(\mathbb R)$ (all the sentences that are true in the reals) that consists just of the algebraic numbers. If we add $\pi$ and $e$ as constants, then the algebraic numbers would no longer be a model because we cannot interpret $\pi$ and $e$ in them. (btw, this theory has a name: "real closed fields" or "RCF")

Comment: Thank you, that makes it much more clear. I did not think about them beeing trancendentel. So constants make a lot of sense, even to me now!